# Google Search Console API not returning all the results

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-developers-console, google-search-console

I am trying to get stats for all the pages in my domain in June. 
When I execute the following request:

```
        request = {
        'startDate': '2021-06-01',
        'endDate': '2021-06-30',
        'dimensions': ['page'],
        'startRow': 25000 * itr,
        'rowLimit': 25000
    }
```

I get 22,500 distinct pages out of 22,500 rows in total 
But if I execute this request:

```
        request = {
        'startDate': '2021-06-01',
        'endDate': '2021-06-30',
        'dimensions': ['query', 'page'],
        'startRow': 25000 * itr,
        'rowLimit': 25000
    }
```

I get 374,295 distinct pages out of 685,331 rows in total. 
I can't understand why I get more pages in the second query. As I understood from the doc dimensions is like group by so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Queries made on Google could contain sensitive data. Therefore, Google is doing some kind of sampling to avoid huge computations by discarding low frequency queries (like long tail queries)
So this is the expected behavior from Google point of view.

source : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553#urlorsite&zippy=%2Cpages%2Cqueries%2Csearch-type-filter-only%2Csearch-appearance